# Adding Sherlock os a Maven dependency behind a firewall and without referenceing a project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

My company operates behind a firewall with no access to outside networks (including the internet.) We use Maven and wish to use the ActionBarSherlock code. There are two problems:

1. If you want to simply include the dependency to the libapk in your pom file, you need internet connectivity to download this file.
2. Otherwise, you must load in the Sherlock as a separate project and reference it in your Android project. This is a hassle in that anybody else that wants to work on the project must download both projects, not to mention that Maven will still not work.

Is there any way to install Sherlock as a true dependency (installed in your Maven repository) without internet and without creating another project?

I tried several things (making a libapk from the actionbarsherlock project and sticking it in the repo, Creating a jar from the actionbarsherlock project and adding it to libs folder - but then you cannot find the resources needed like themes, adding the .jar file in to maven) but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to install the lib to your local repository? then you can build you application using: '-o' argument (=offline) for example: maven -o package

Answer (score 2):

You can manually install jars into your local maven repository:

[Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Later if maven tries to access internet when compiling or on other phase you can use mvn -o to manage dependencies offline